# Is it possible to deploy Silverlight Apps on Android?

Tags: c#, android, silverlight

Hello Guys I simply want to ask that is it possible to deploy **Silverlight** Apps on Android.

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk, but I wanted to point out it's spelled 'possible'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's nothing on this platform yet that allows you to run Silverlight applications. The upcoming [Windows Phone 7](http://developer.windowsphone.com/) platform will allow running Silverlight and XNA applications.

My expectations are from [MonoDroid](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/May-21.html) to come first which will bring C# to Android and after maybe [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) could be ported.

Comment: May be in the near future Microsoft Provides Silverlight For Android based Mobiles.

Comment: Yes, maybe some day but I wouldn't say in the near future. They first  need to put and establish their phone on the market or it will be a risky endeavor. I expect Moonlight to appear first as they are working on a MonoDroid (running Mono on Android) which will allow developing applications on C# instead of Java that target the Android platform.

Comment: wouldn't moonlight then be a way of running silverlight apps on android?

Comment: No, the Silverlight client is not part of Moonlight. These are different frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some work being done to port Moonlight to Android. They've got a demo of it here:

http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2011/04/moonlight-on-android.html

Answer (score -2):

Yep, I suppose that the guys from Google will consider SL support for Android in addition to Flash, and I bet this will not be so far away in the future :)

Dick